# How would I lookup certain GPU information

Tags: javascript, ajax, gpu

So I'm wanting to make a website where you can search for information about GPU's but I am unable to find a site that will provide the specification could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WEBGL_debug_renderer_info` via a canvas context. Not all browsers would support this extension.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("testcanvas");
var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");

var info = gl.getExtension("WEBGL_debug_renderer_info");
var renderer = gl.getParameter(info.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL);
var vendor = gl.getParameter(info.UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL);

console.log(renderer);
console.log(vendor);
```

```html
<canvas id="testcanvas" width="0" height="0"></canvas>
```